# Uncaught ReferenceError: then is not defined in Element Ui Plus

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using the `vue3` and `element-ui-plus` to build a project.

But when I tried to use the `MessageBox` in `element-ui-plus`, there was an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: then is not defined` coming out.

Other functions are good except `MessageBox`.

Here is my code. And Please refer to the `handleDelete` function.

```
    <script src="../js/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugins/elementui/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/axios-0.18.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        const app ={
            el: '#app',
            data(){
                return {
                    pagination: {
                        currentPage: 1,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        total: 0,
                        queryString: null
                    },

                    formData: {},


                }
            },
            created() {
                this.findPage();
            },
            methods: {
                findPage() {
                    var param = {
                        currentPage: this.pagination.queryString == null ? this.pagination.currentPage : 1,
                        pageSize: this.pagination.pageSize,
                        queryString: this.pagination.queryString
                    };
                    axios.post("/checkitem/findPage.do",param).then(res => {
                        this.pagination.total = res.data.total;
                        this.dataList = res.data.rows;
                    });

                },
                resetForm() {
                    this.formData = {};
                },
                handleDelete(row) {
                    this.$confirm("Do you want to delete the record?","Warning",{
                        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                        cancelButtonText: "No",
                        type: "warning"
                    }).then(() => {
                        console.log("delete record");
                        axios.get("/checkitem/delete.do?id="+row.id).then(res => {

                        });
                    }).catch(() => {

                    });


                }
            }
        };
        Vue.createApp(app).use(ElementPlus).mount("#app");
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Oliver you could try making your function `async`. See below

```
async handleDelete(row) {
  try {
      await this.$confirm("Do you want to delete the record?","Warning",{
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        type: "warning"
    })
    console.log("delete record")
    axios.get("/checkitem/delete.do?id="+row.id)
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  } finally {
    // something else if you need
  }
})
```

Question though, are you meant to be waiting for a user to confirm/cancel the click before you trigger execute the delete?

Comment: I suppose yes. Here is [Element+'s documentation about messagebox](https://element-plus.org/#/en-US/component/message-box), and according to this, `then` should be defined well inside the library.

Comment: sry for late reply.  thank you and this post fixed my problem

Comment: No problem @Oliver, glad it helped! If you could mark it as the accepted answer that would be awesome :)